# Passing parameter from Middleware to Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a middleware which does a query and I would like to pass the result back to my controller. Is it possible? I'm using Laravel 5.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return view('errors.401');
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
            }
        }

        $cur_route = Request::segment(1);

        $result = DB::table('t_user_acl_masters')->join('t_function_details', 't_function_details.functiondtl_id', '=' ,'t_user_acl_masters.functiondtl_id')
                                                ->where('t_function_details.routename', '=', $cur_route)
                                                ->where('t_user_acl_masters.user_id', '=', $request->user()->user_id)
                                                ->select('t_user_acl_masters.viewaccess','t_user_acl_masters.addaccess','t_user_acl_masters.editaccess','t_user_acl_masters.deleteaccess')
                                                ->first();

        if(!empty($result)) {
            if ($result->viewaccess != 'y') {
                return view('errors.401');
            }
        }

        return $next($request, $result);
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        $this->acl = $request->attributes->get('acl');
    }

public function index(Request $request){
        dd($this->acl);
}
```

I have injected it in to the attributes of request, but I can't get it from my function. If I dd($request->attributes->get('acl')) in my index() function, data is available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Pass Data from Middleware to Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374425/laravel-5-pass-data-from-middleware-to-controller)

Comment: How can i pass it back and display it in my constructor? Because now if i set it to flash session, it can only be obtained on a function and not other functions.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe this isn't something that should be done in a middleware.

Comment: In the middlewear, I will query out the user's access control. I would like to pass it back to my __construct so that I do not need to query it again. The data will be needed in most of the functions in my controller. Every single page will need this query and the query is different based on the route that is queried.

Comment: But you only select the column `viewaccess` if I read that correctly. Based on that you decide if you throw a `401` or not. Why do you need to save that?

Comment: Sorry i've added in other datas, i will need them on my controllers.

Comment: So if I see this right: You use middleware to determine if a user has the right to do something but you only use it for `viewaccess`? The validation for the other ACLs is happening in your controller?

Comment: Viewaccess determines if the user have access to the page, then on the page i will have delete, add or update buttons, it will also determine if the user is able to delete add or update in my controller.

Comment: Well how about that: You are already getting the first segment of the URL from your Request object. The 2nd segment will probably reflect the action you want to take (add, edit, delete) just like in your acl_table.
Why don't refactor the middleware to dynamically check these?

Comment: But how do I pass them to the view? Lets say the user does not have editaccess, the edit button would not show.

Comment: That's a job for so called abilities. Check the documentation on Authorization: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization

Comment: Middle**ware** and controller(s) have access to the same object - the `Request`. Inject the value into the `Request` object in your middleware after you're done with the query. All controllers and all views will have access to it.

Comment: I've updated my question with the Request injection. I cant seem to get data from my __construct though.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the variable in the session:

```
Session::flash('result', $result);
```

Then you can retrieve it in your controller like so:

```
Session::get('result');
```

Comment: when i use Session::get('result') in my __construct, i get null. But if it's in current view function, I am able to get it.

Comment: Thats because the constructor is executed before the middleware kicks in. You shouldn't try to set variables from the middleware to the constructor of the controller, that's backwards order of doing things